# Anyone know of a blast (explosive) forming vendor for tank domes?

Tags: tanks

We're looking to fabricate some Titanium tank domes of fairly thin gage (~ 1mm) and about 20" diameter for a low cost mission.  There's lots of articles about explosive forming for this, but as far as I can tell there are no active fabricators specializing in this technique.  Does anyone know of someone we could approach to get a quote, preferably in the US?

Comment: You could look up Hermetic Solutions Group. I don't actually know anything about them except that they say they do it. Just ran across them.
https://www.hermeticsolutions.com/products/explosively-bonded-metals/explosive-hydro-forming/

Comment: Thanks, Greg!  Great suggestion!

Answer (score 6):

Saw a bunch of refs in this article:
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/275566777_EXPLOSIVE_FORMING_-_ECONOMICAL_TECHNOLOGY_FOR_AEROSPACE_STRUCTURES

Paper is dated 2010.  I did work on Apollo program some time ago at North American Aviation (long gone) who did explosive forming and I remember Aerojet General in Sacramento doing that also but these are only for historical purposes, of course.  But Rocketdyne (used to be a division of North American) is still in existence and could be a source. It is now a division of Aerojet.  There are other refs in this paper that could be active but they do not appear to be located in US.  A word of caution, don't use any Russian vendors.